# Angular - Add compiled html snippet, dynamicly to a directive, before the directive gets compiled

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a directive into another directive dynamically in Ionic for Example:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  // If the page has my-directive, add here a my-button to control it
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I'm trying to do this from another directive, which is more deeper.
my try on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/remrYw?editors=1010).

**Background:**
I want, that if I use `my-directive` somewhere deeper, that `my-directive` adds dynamically a button to the `navbar`, which can control the `my-directive`.

**Edit:** I tried it again [codepen 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOXJge?editors=1010), but there are still some issues:

- When going to a page where the directive isn't present, the button should also be removed.
- The button only appears, when you directly start on the page where the directive is. If you start somewhere else and navigate to it, it doesn't work.
- Somewhere I have a $timeout wich waits 0 milliseconds, doesn't work without, but why should this be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directive for your navbar and pass the markup to the directive's isoltated scope.

Passing can be done with `$rootScope` or with a factory. I would prefer a factory but in the demo I've used the rootScope for passing.

I also don't like the scope passing in the demo. It's working but I think it would be better to store the handler in a factory too. The factory can then manage the creation of the icon in navbar and the event handler for the action you need for the button.

Please have a look at the following demo or in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VabJax?editors=1011).

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
  
  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: "/check-in",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/check-in.html",
          controller: "CheckinCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: "/attendees",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/attendees.html",
          controller: "AttendeesCtrl"
        }
      }
    })
  
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
})

.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
    console.log('entered');
  });
})

.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope) {
})
.directive( 'dynNavbar', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      optional: '='
    },
    template: '<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button><div class="dynButton"/>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('optional', function(){
        var dynButton = scope.optional; 
        console.log(scope.optional, element, element[0].querySelector('.dynButton'), $compile(dynButton.html)(scope));
       angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.dynButton')).replaceWith($compile(dynButton.html)(dynButton.scope));
      });
      
    }
  }
})
.directive('test', function($compile) {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p ng-style="{color: styleFlag}">use this directive, with the button in the navbar</p>',
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
          $rootScope.injectedButton = {html: '<a class="button button-icon icon ion-eye" ng-click="cry()"></a>',
            scope: $scope
          };             
          var styleFlag = false;
          
          $scope.cry = function () {
              console.log('buhuhuhu');
              styleFlag = !styleFlag; // change style just as example
              $scope.styleFlag = styleFlag ? 'red': 'black';
              //console.log(styleFlag, $scope.styleFlag);
            };
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            
            // -----------------------------------
            // ADD BUTTON IN NAVBAR
            // -----------------------------------
            //scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
             /*   var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar-block');
                if (nav[0].getAttribute('nav-bar') == 'active' || nav[0].getAttribute('nav-bar') == 'entering') {
                    nav = angular.element(nav[0].getElementsByClassName('right-buttons')[0]);
                }
                if (nav[1] && nav[1].getAttribute('nav-bar') == 'active' || nav[1] && nav[1].getAttribute('nav-bar') == 'entering') {
                    nav = angular.element(nav[1].getElementsByClassName('right-buttons')[0]);
                }
              console.log(nav);
                nav.append($compile('<a class="button button-icon icon ion-eye" ng-click="cry()"></a>')(scope));
            // });
*/
            // -----------------------------------
            // FUNCTION FOR THE BUTTON
            // -----------------------------------
            /*scope.cry = function () {
              console.log('buhuhuhu');
            };*/
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Side Menus</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
            
            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
              <!--<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>-->
              <dyn-navbar optional="injectedButton"/>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content> 

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ul class="list">
              <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item" menu-close>Check-in</a>
              <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item" menu-close>Attendees</a>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Welcome">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          home: <test></test>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/check-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Check-in">
        <ion-content>
          checkin: <test></test>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/attendees.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Attendees">
        <ion-content>
          attendees: <test></test>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool thanks a lot, but it only works on the initial loading of the codepen. I also tried to make it with a factory as you supposed, but it still has some issues see the updated question.

Comment: I still don't know why your updated points are not working. It's probably related to ionic but I couldn't find why. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nbu9c3kb/9/) is a working demo with-out ionic and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nbu9c3kb/8/) with ionic. Sorry, that I couldn't find a fix.

Comment: thank you a lot for the work! it really is an ionic issue, they are making a lot of stuff more complicated and almost impossible. Anyway I go to accept your answer, for your hard tryings to help me.